# prevent class modification from browser consol (security issue)

Tags: php, html, css, security

I'm  a student in development (2nd year). I'm currently in internship and one of my task is to add an authentication system to a website.

It "works" , but I think it's a pretty bad code and i'm looking for an advice on best practice and improving this solution.

The project is just a regular stock management system, and a menu allow the user to choose read or write, then (after a click) a scrolling menu let them choose from more option.

The page contain this class :

```
<style type="text/css">
  /* a li.unclickable  { text-decoration: none; } */
  /* a li.unclickable:hover { cursor: default; } */
  .unclickable {
    pointer-events:none; 
    opacity:0.7;         
  }
</style>
```

and the authentification is only used here:

```
<?php
if ($admin =="1") {
    echo '<li>';
}
else {
    echo '<li class="unclickable" >';
}
?>
//some code then
</li>
```

`$admin` value is 0 or 1 , stored in a session, and everything work well in theory and I could get away with that, but you just have to press F12 and edit the class (just delete it), and the whole authentication system become useless.

is there a way to prevent the user from doing that ,or should I choose another approach to the problem?

The company would probably not find out, because they dont have any dev/tech guy, but I dont think it's okay to give them this and say it's flawless.

I'm using PHP in MVC, any advices or questions are welcome, thanks for your time.

Comment: you have no way to ensure that the HTML/JS/CSS code you send to the client will not be changed. that's why you always have to validate the user input and user authentication on the server side even if it is already done on the client side. You can keep your class `unclickable` and on the server side, add some code to check if the user is admin on each action that requires admin rights. this way, even if someone changes the CSS, your app will still be protected.

Comment: Also, *the company would probably not find out* => perhaps this is true but someone with bad intentions will find it

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to block browser devtools. HTML page is in full control of the user. Every security check must be done server-side.

The right place to do that is in the login page (the one that gets called by pressing the button), checking again the value of `$admin` before any authentication logic.